# how to insert a row in table , mysql using bash - when $ is used?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to insert a row in MySQL table using bash, I have saved the below script as **script.sh** and I run using

**bash script.sh**

When the script is executed, it is successful with no errors but the password field which contains an encrypted value(**'$2b$10$FywS3Lc27let0C9VVvZYFOBYg.AwGA3VEtUs5YIAjjUWSSEI3Fqt2'**) is stored as some other value like

**b0.AwGA3VEtUs5YIAjjUWSSEI3Fqt2**

instead of

**$2b$10$FywS3Lc27let0C9VVvZYFOBYg.AwGA3VEtUs5YIAjjUWSSEI3Fqt2**

I tried using '' and "" and `` , all of them didn't work

So how do I insert when having an $ value ?

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql <<EOF
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO "test_mysql_user"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "test_password";

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
create database cricket;
use cricket;

//created tables 
.....
.....

INSERT INTO admin
(
admin_id,
first_name,
middle_name,
last_name,
email_id,
password,
address,
city,
state,
zip_code,
country,
phone_code,
phone_number,
email_campaign)
VALUES
(
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root@gmail.com',
'$2b$10$FywS3Lc27let0C9VVvZYFOBYg.AwGA3VEtUs5YIAjjUWSSEI3Fqt2', //this field is the error , saved as someother value
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root');
EOF
```

Comment: consider using source command. That may be a quick workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to quote the `'EOF'` string for if you want no parameter substitution.

From `man bash | less +/"Here Documents"`

**Here Documents**

This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the current source until a line  containing  only  word
(with  no  trailing  blanks) is seen.  All of the lines read up to that point are then used as the standard input for a
command.

The format of here-documents is:

```
<<[-]word
        here-document
delimiter
```

No parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on word.  If any
characters in word are quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the here-document
are not expanded.  **If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to  parameter  expansion,  command
substitution,  and  arithmetic expansion**.  In the latter case, the character sequence <newline> is ignored, and \ must
be used to quote the characters , $, and `.

If the redirection operator is <<-, then all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and the line contain-
ing delimiter.  This allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion.

So, your script should look like this when you quote the 'EOF' string

```
mysql <<'EOF'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO "test_mysql_user"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "test_password";

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
create database cricket;
use cricket;

//created tables 
.....
.....

INSERT INTO admin
(
admin_id,
first_name,
middle_name,
last_name,
email_id,
password,
address,
city,
state,
zip_code,
country,
phone_code,
phone_number,
email_campaign)
VALUES
(
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root@gmail.com',
'$2b$10$FywS3Lc27let0C9VVvZYFOBYg.AwGA3VEtUs5YIAjjUWSSEI3Fqt2', 
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root');
EOF
```

If quoting `word` is not an option for you and want to avoid the parameter substitution just for the encrypted password field, store the encrypted  value in a variable and use that variable in the doc.

```
password='$2b$10$FywS3Lc27let0C9VVvZYFOBYg.AwGA3VEtUs5YIAjjUWSSEI3Fqt2'

mysql <<EOF
INSERT INTO admin
(
admin_id,
first_name,
middle_name,
last_name,
email_id,
password,
address,
city,
state,
zip_code,
country,
phone_code,
phone_number,
email_campaign)
VALUES
(
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root@gmail.com',
'$password',
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root',
'root');
EOF
```